# Missing salt rounds error

Tags: grails, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm trying to configure bcrypt as the encryption algorithm in Grails 2.1.1 and spring-security-core 1.2.7.3, following the [instructions](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/12%20Password%20and%20Account%20Protection.html#12.1%20Password%20Encryption). In Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.bcrypt.logrounds = 100
```

I was previously using a salt and it was working fine, but for this change I edited my User.encodePassword() to the one argument version.

When I create a new user in Bootstrap.groovy and try to save it:

```
testUser = new User(username: 'name@example.com', enabled: true, password: 'password').save(flush: true)
```

I get this error:

```
Message: Missing salt rounds
    Line | Method
->>  678 | hashpw                       in org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     44 | encodePassword               in grails.plugins.springsecurity.BCryptPasswordEncoder
|     87 | encodePassword . . . . . . . in grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
|     42 | encodePassword               in com.madeupname.app.User
|     32 | beforeInsert . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     46 | onApplicationEvent           in org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener
|     27 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1_closure3_closure4
|    314 | execute                      in grails.util.Environment$EnvironmentBlockEvaluator
|    295 | executeForEnvironment . . .  in grails.util.Environment
|    270 | executeForCurrentEnvironment in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                          in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run                          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Any idea of what I might have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that for this implementation you have to specify a value between 4 and 31. I've updated the docs.